# DrawHole custom geometry function not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

DrawHole has an undocumented option to use a custom geometry function which is not working :

```
var geomFn = options.geometryFunction
if (geomFn) {
    options.geometryFunction = function (c, g) {
        g = _geometryFn(c, g)
        return geomFn(c, g)
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

If it is changed to the code below it works :

```
var geomFn = options.geometryFunction
if (geomFn) {
    options.geometryFunction = function (c, g) {
        g = _geometryFn.bind(this)(c, g)
        return geomFn.bind(this)(c, g)
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It should be possible but currently is not working, I raised an issue https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/issues/978